# Linq Foreach doesn't change values

Tags: c#

I have a collection I want to change values with linq

```
List<string> d = new List<string> { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
d.ForEach(x => x = "w");
```

Above code doesn't change it. List still have empty strings after.
Why?

How to change it the correct way instead?

The ugly way I found is:

```
IEnumerable<string> d = new List<string> { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
d = d.Select(x => { x = "C"; return x; });
```

Comment: FYI: `ForEach` is a `List<T>` method, it's not LINQ. Another FYI: `string`s are immutable. Another `FYI`: you're changing the *reference* of `x`, not its value, in the first implementation

Comment: 1 FYI, ok but useless. 2 FYI And? I'm trying to replace them anyway 3 FYI Whatever, I just need them to point to the right value, what's the matter if I change the reference?

Comment: The problem is that you can't change a reference inside a `ForEach` or with any LINQ method for that matter. Your last example is the same as `Enumerable.Range(0, itemsLength).Select(c => "c");` (see how it doesn't even need the reference to `d`?)

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable passes each item by value, not by reference, so there is no way of editing it. LINQ is not designed for side-affecting operators.

The best way is just to loop the List.

```
for (var i = 0; i < d.Count; i++)
    d[i] = "w";
```

Comment: There must be a cleaner way

Comment: This will not work since `d` is defined as an `IEnumerable`

Comment: @juharr Well, it's once defined as `List<T>` and another time as `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: This is the cleanest. Certainly the fastest. Although if you want to stick to LINQ you could do `Enumerable.Range(0, d.Count - 1).All(i => { d[i] = "x"; return true; })` but that's just daft.

Comment: @Charlieface Actually that should be `Range(0, d.Count)` as the second values in the count and not an end number.

Comment: @juharr Arghh, and I originally wrote that then edited it!

Comment: @ThrowAwayLiquidCore It is two lines of code, it expresses very clearly exactly what is happening, it is the fastest method - what do you think would be cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

Charlieface answer is in my opinion the best way to do it. But here is your ugly way with Linq a little less ugly. Beware it will **create a new List** and not just change every values

```
List<string> d = new List<string> { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
d = d.Select(x => "w").ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

The functionality you want does not exist, but it is easy to implement it if you so wish. You need to include in your project an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for the `List<T>` type, like the one below:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void UpdateAll<T>(this List<T> source,
        Func<T, T> newValueSelector)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
            source[i] = newValueSelector(source[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use it with any `List<T>` instance inside your project, like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
list.UpdateAll(x => "w");
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", list));
```

Output:

```xml
w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w, w
```